# Vagrant ssh with multiple arguments

Tags: python, ssh, vagrant

I am having problems executing multiple commands with vagrant ssh.

In order to run some tests in vagrant environment I execute following commands:

1. `vagrant ssh app`
2. `sudo su deploy`
3. `cd /some/dir/for/test`
4. `source env/bin/activate`
5. `python manage.py test`

I managed to get to point 3 but could not execute the 4th point. My attempt is as follows:

```
vagrant ssh app -- -t 'cd /some/dir/for/test; sudo su deploy'
```

But after the sudo command if I write some more commands they are not executed.

I will also need to redirect the tests output to original shell, outside the vagrant environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it all in a single command:

```
vagrant ssh app -- -t 'sudo -u deploy /some/dir/for/test/env/bin/python /some/dir/for/test/env/manage.py test'
```

here you can avoid the useless `su` call by giving an argument to `sudo` so it runs a command as the given user, using the `-u` argument. Then the `bin/activate` command  is only changing the environment, so the python you're calling thereafter is the one from `env/bin/python`, so you can directly call it using its full path.

And for your knowledge, if you want to chain two commands separated by `;` in a single sudo call, you shall spawn a shell in your sudo command, i.e.: `sudo sh -c "run this; run that"`.