# Invoke FastDownward planner from Python with Vagrant in Windows 10 / Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, subprocess, vagrant

I am trying to invoke FastDownward planner with the use of Vagrant from my python script.

I have tried os library but failed.

Then I have tried different things like that with subprocesses:

```
    cmd = ['downward/fast-downward.py', "--alias", "lama-first", "/vagrant/domain.pddl", "/vagrant/problem.pddl"]
    retcode = subprocess.call(cmd)

    print(retcode)
```

it outputs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C: / ... .py", line 124, in
>
> main (sys.argv [1:])
>     File "C: / ... .py", line 111, in main
>
> retcode = subprocess.call (cmd)
>
> File "C: \ .... \ Anaconda3 \ lib \ subprocess.py", line 323, in call
>
> with Popen (* popenargs, ** kwargs) as p:
>
> File "C: \ ...... \ Anaconda3 \ lib \ subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
>        restore_signals, start_new_session)
>
> File "C: \ ..... \ Anaconda3 \ lib \ subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
>        startupinfo)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Cannot find the specified file from the system

I have also tried that:

```
    retcode = subprocess.call("vagrant up")
    retcode = subprocess.call("vagrant ssh")
    cmd = ['downward/fast-downward.py', "--alias", "lama-first", "/vagrant/domain.pddl", "/vagrant/problem.pddl"]
    retcode = subprocess.call(cmd)

    print(retcode)
```

But these stuck on ssh and it cannot be correct, it takes a lot of time to start a vagrant environment.

This is my work environment:
[image: Text]

Thank you

EDIT:

I have tried those links but I cannot make Vagrant Option appear in pycharm:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/vagrant-support.html#

https://medium.com/@krishna.yerramsetty/remote-python-development-environment-using-pycharm-and-vagrant-32f1ac3c66b8

https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/a-tutorial-on-application-development-using-vagrant-with-the-pycharm-ide/

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I managed to directly run an ssh command to vagrant from my python script. In this case I run fast-downward planner:

```
output=os.popen("vagrant ssh default -- -t 'downward/fast-downward.py --alias lama-first /vagrant/domain.pddl /vagrant/problem.pddl'").read()
```

the above solution saves the output string in the variable `output`. You can use this to just print the output to the terminal:

```
os.system("vagrant ssh default -- -t 'downward/fast-downward.py --alias lama-first /vagrant/domain.pddl /vagrant/problem.pddl'")
```

and you can run multiple commands after `-t`, seperating them with semicolons `'command1; command2;...'` judging [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41728857/7919440) (i haven't tried that).

You can use *subprocess* library instead of *os*, and you can split `output` string variable to a list of strings with `output=output.split()`

I hope I help, as the vagrant documentation is not complete and there are not many examples online for Windows